# Migrate from SP2010 to SP2013. Please advice for service applications migrate plan

Tags: migration

I setup a blank new SP2013 farm and going to migrate a SP2010 farm to there. According to MS's [Overview of the upgrade process to SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
Follow 6 service applications can be migrated:

Business Data Connectivity service application
Managed Metadata service application
PerformancePoint Services service application
Search service application
Secure Store Service application
User Profile service application

Do I need to migrate all of them?

I don't think they have setup any BDC and Performance point. Also I think SP2013 have an improved search service (the old sp2010 farm do not have FAST) so maybe I don't need search service migrate.

I think only user profile and managed metadata need to be moved. Is it viable and did I miss anything? Thanks for your experience share.

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate the services that you are using in 2010.

Otherwise in Sharepoint 2013 you can use new services in new farm.

Answer (score 1):

yes, MSFT support upgrade for 6 Services applications. Personally, i would always recommend( i adopted) create new search services application and run ful crawl in new farm.

For UPA & MMS, tip is make sure MMS upgraded before the UPA. Once you upgrade the MMS then UPA then configure the sync and run full sync.

Before migrating the above services application, make sure service instances are running in the farm.

check this techent for more info.
[Upgrade service applications to SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj839719.aspx)